# Javascript maths, from input field to h2 tag

Tags: javascript

Ok we have an input field. Example:

```
<input id="weeklyRent" name="weeklyRent" size="50" type="text" class="medium">
```

What I wish to do, is add a listener to this field, and when the user has clicked out of the field, to perform some maths, and spew out the answer to h2 tag.

For arguments sake, we shall say weekly amount user inputs is 280

1. d=280/7
2. y=365 x d
3. m=y/12

### Print value m

Where m is the calculated monthly value.

d=day | m=month | y=year

I know purists will throw into the mix leap years etc, but we need as close to this for proximity reasons.
Oh and round up to nearest EVEN (whole) number would be useful

Comment: lol cheers Jeff, I amended after realising my algebra was crap, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an `onBlur` handler to your `input`. Have that handler to all the necessary work:

```
// the js function
function doMath() {
   var rent = this.value;
   var d = rent/7;
   var y = 365 * d;
   var m = y/12;
   document.getElementById("idForH2").innerHTML = m;
}

document.getElementById("weeklyRent").onblur = doMath;
```

[Here's a working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bWeR9/11/).

[Here's a direct copy/pastable example](http://jsfiddle.net/cCYep/) in the way that you are trying to implement it. You have to attach the code to the `window.onload` event in an anonymous function so the code won't execute until the window has completely loaded.

I would *highly* recommend, however, that if you are going to be doing some work in javascript, that you start learning more about it from w3school, various books, or whatever learning source you like. This helps you understand more and  helps you ask more *specific questions* rather than asking for complete code examples to do what you want. Which is fine, but I'm sure you'd rather learn for yourself.

I wish you luck on your javascript adventures!

Comment: You can set jsfiddle to **not** wrap your Javascript in a onload event so that the function will still be in the correct scrope. Also, why can't you attach an event handler instead of using inline events? http://jsfiddle.net/yijiang/bWeR9/5/

Comment: @Yi Jiang Ah! I was not thinking clearly in the context of jsFiddle. I could and should have done that.

Comment: Yep gottya, but unless I add the js after the blur, I cannot get it to display. Seems your fiddle, works great, but soon as i strip back the js in the html portion, it fails.

Comment: @422 I have updated my answer, thanks to Yi Jiang's reminder. Now I attach the onblur handler in the javascript. See my updated fiddle linked in my answer. All should be well.

Comment: So where am i going wrong, I cannot get it to display:
<code><script type="text/javascript">
// the js function
function doMath() {
   var d = this.value/7;
   var y = 365 * d;
   var m = y/12;
   document.getElementById("monthlyRent").innerHTML = m;
}

document.getElementById("weeklyRent").onblur = doMath;
  </script>
 </HEAD>

 <BODY>
 <!-- the input element with the onClick handler -->
<input id="weeklyRent" name="weeklyRent" size="50" type="text" class="medium">
<h2 id="monthlyRent"></h2></code>

Comment: @422 I do not know unless you edit your question with your *live* code. The code that you are using on your website.

Comment: @422 wrap that in a window.onload

Comment: Thanks Alex, I thought that was the ethos os SO. Finally have it working, thanks. Now I will go searching and learning on how to round up and round down, and play silly buggers. Much appreciated, voted accordingly. Regards Ste

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you know javascript:
**event Onblur**
This event takes places when objects lose focus. If you click inside one text box then click outside it the textbox has lost focus. That's when the onBlur event fires.

```
<INPUT TYPE = text onBlur = "alert('Lost focus')">
```

Answer (score 1):

You will use the `onblur` event to call a function, and the function will look something like:

```
function blah() {
    t=document.getElementById('weeklyRent').value;
    // Calculate the value of t here
    h2=document.getElementById('h2 element');
    h2.innerHTML=t;
}
```

You will need to set the id weeklyRent on the text field and an id on the h2 element.